# Inserting a list within a list

Tags: c#

As of now, I have two lists, one comprises of a list of students, the other, a list of classrooms, what I want to do is, after creating a classroom and creating a list of students, how would I go about copying the list of students to the classroom.

Say I create a classroom called "Chemistry" that gets added to the classroom list (element 0) once I enter a list of students, how would I copy/place that list of students within the classroom.

I understand if the question is a little vague, it's basically so I can create classrooms dynamically and simply add a list of students to any classroom I create.

Thank you for your time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace P3_O_O_P
{
    public class Classroom
    {
        public List<Module> roomList;

        public Classroom()
        {
            roomList = new List<Module>();
        }

        public void createClassRoom(Module objMod)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter room name: ");
            objMod.ModuleName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("\nEnter a module I.D. code: ");
            objMod.ModuleID = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            roomList.Add(new Module(objMod.ModuleName, objMod.ModuleID));
        }

        public void classList()
        {
            foreach (var module in roomList)
            {
                Console.Write("\nModule: " + module);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addStudent(Student student, Module objMod, Classroom objClassroom, int mark)
    {
        objMod.registerList.Add(new Registration(student, mark));

        objMod.Enrol(student, Mark, objClassroom);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd modify the `Classroom` class to include a `List<Student>`.

Make the setter private so that the list cannot be set to `null` or instantiated to a new list outside of the `Classroom` class. The public getter allows you to call `Add()`, `Remove()`, etc.

```
public class Classroom
{
    ...
    public List<Student> Students { get; private set; }

    public Classroom()
    {
        ...
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then add to the list inside your method:

```
public void addStudent(Student student, Module objMod, Classroom objClassroom, int mark)
{
    ...

    objClassroom.Students.Add(student);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, you beat me to it.

Comment: The addStudent method is within a different class, I forgot to add the class header for it above, would this allow me to create not only a classroom but also insert a list of students? I need to be able to create classrooms with the module name and ID then simply add students to that newly created classroom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it like you would in a database, e.g. create an List of an associative type

```
public class StudentsClassrooms
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int ClassroomId { get; set; }
}

public List<StudentsClassrooms> associations = new List<StudentsClassrooms>();
```

Then you could join them together and query them with Linq.